# Superfluidity book recommendation

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, superfluidity

I'm preparing for a senior undergrad seminar on superfluidity and quantized vortices, and my professor seems to prefer old textbooks, so I wondered what modern (~90's onwards) books on these phenomena exists.

I'm looking for an introductory text with a theoretical approach, and I have a good basis of QM, statistical physics and thermodynamics. Preferably it mentions vorticity, critical velocities or neutron stars.

Comment: I'm not sure about neutron stars (not star*t*s I guess), but the [book by Leggett](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/quantum-liquids-9780198526438?cc=fr&lang=en&) is excellent : *Quantum liquids* at Oxford Publishing. If you need a simpler book, try [Annett : *Superconductivity, Superfluidity and Condensates*](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/superconductivity-superfluids-and-condensates-9780198507567?cc=fr&lang=en&), also at Oxford University press.

Comment: And about modern aspects on topological phases, try the book by [Volovik *The universe in a helium droplet*](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-universe-in-a-helium-droplet-9780198507826?cc=fr&lang=en&), also at Oxford (I'm not an Oxford agent :-) but be aware it's quite a tough reading.

Comment: For superfluid critical velocity and vorticity in neutron stars: [Insights into the physics of neutron star interiors from pulsar glitches](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2301.12769). More about "the universe in a helium droplet": https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/589595/226902